# eBPF: running in Linux namespaces

Tags: bpf, linux-namespaces, ebpf

So `BPF` programs are the kernel entities, as they run within the kernel space. On the other hand, Linux namespaces aka containers, provide application-level isolation, in which case they all share the host's kernel, kernel modules etc.

So I guess it doesn't make sense to load a `bpf` program per container, as it will become visible on the host as well?

Therefore I would guess that `bpf` programs would load on the host and monitor/mangle/etc. packets to/from namespaces. Given that `struct sock` has the information about namespace id, I think only certain types of `bpf` programs would be able to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I guess it doesn't make sense to load a `bpf` program per container, as it will become visible on the host as well?

If you mean loading a BPF program *from* a container, then yes it would be visible on the host as well (and you would need a privileged container in order to do that).

> Given that `struct sock` has the information about namespace id, I think only certain types of `bpf` programs would be able to do that?

I couldn't find any BPF program type that has direct access to `struct sock`. [BPF programs of type sockops](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/91ab883eb21325ad80f3473633f794c78ac87f51/samples/bpf/test_cgrp2_sock.c) have access to [`struct bpf_sock`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16-rc2/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L881), but it contains few actual information.

You could use [BPF programs of type cgroup/skb](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/91ab883eb21325ad80f3473633f794c78ac87f51/samples/bpf/test_cgrp2_attach.c) though. Those are attached to cgroups and can act on both ingress and egress packets. They receive a [`struct __sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16-rc2/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L820) object as argument, a mirror of the `sk_buff` for the packet received/sent. They can only use [a few helpers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16-rc2/source/net/core/filter.c#L3448) (in addition to the common base), and don't seem to have write access to packets.

[kprobe BPF programs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/91ab883eb21325ad80f3473633f794c78ac87f51/samples/bpf/tracex1_kern.c) have access to any kernel function kprobes can be attached to. So you could retrieve the namespace information by probing the appropriate function and then send it to your monitor/mangle/etc. program through a bpf map. Not the simplest option though.